# std::string part into integer

Tags: c++, string, int

I have a std::string: `01001`, I want to get each number:

```
std::string foo = "01001";
for (int i=0; i < foo.size(); ++i)
{
   int res = atoi( foo[i] );  // fail
   int res = atoi( &foo[i] ); // ok, but res = 0 in any case
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the easiest way I see:

```
std::string foo = "01001";
for (int i=0; i < foo.size(); ++i)
{
   int res = foo[i] - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you know all characters of `foo` are digits, you can use `(int) (foo[i] - '0')` which subtracts the ascii value of `'0'` from the character. This works for all digits because their ascii values are consecutive.

Your first attempt fails because `foo[i]` is a single `char`, while `atoi()` takes a cstring. Your second attempt fails because `&foo[i]` is a reference to that character.

Comment: C and C++ both require that the values used to represent the decimal digits are consecutive; it's not strictly dependent upon the character set.

Answer (score 3):

Each digit can be obtained by simply using subtraction:

```
int res = foo[i] - '0';
```

`atoi` takes a null-terminated string, not an individual character.  The subtraction approach works because the ten decimal digits are guaranteed to be consecutive in the character set (obviously, if there is a chance that you'll have nondigit characters in the string, you'll want to do proper error handling).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way, very close to what you have, would be to insert the char into a predefined string, as such:

```
std::string foo = "01001";
char str[] = {" "};
for (int i=0; i < foo.size(); ++i)
{
   str[0] = foo[i];
   int res = atoi( str );
}
```